# Who has ownership of a struct's members in a function that takes &self?

Tags: struct, rust, ownership

I am trying to write a small wrapper around `VecDeque`.

Specifically I have the code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c9fc43f0903b753082ea1c66444d9bcc&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

trait VecCircleTraits<T: Eq> {
    fn new() -> VecCircle<T>;
    fn find_and_remove(&self, _: T) -> Option<T>;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct VecCircle<T: Eq>(VecDeque<T>);

impl<T: Eq> VecCircleTraits<T> for VecCircle<T> {
    fn new() -> VecCircle<T> {
        return VecCircle(VecDeque::<T>::new());
    }

    fn find_and_remove(&self, key: T) -> Option<T> {
        let search_index: Option<usize> = self.0.into_iter().position(|x| x == key); //error 1
        if let Some(index) = search_index {
            return self.0.remove(index); // error 2
        } else {
            return None;
        }
    }
}
```

Which gives me the following errors:

```
    error: cannot borrow immutable anonymous field `self.0` as mutable
  --> <anon>:20:20
   |>
20 |>             return self.0.remove(index); // error 2
   |>                    ^^^^^^

error: cannot move out of borrowed content [--explain E0507]
  --> <anon>:18:44
   |>
18 |>         let search_index: Option<usize> =  self.0.into_iter().position(|x| x == key); //error 1
   |>                                            ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

However, I am little confused as who has ownership over `self.0`? If I am understanding the docs correctly, wouldn't the memory region be bounded to `self.0` and therefore giving it the ownership? Sorry for the shallow logic there but I am still trying to understand the ownership system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `find_and_remove`, you specified `&self` in the parameter list. This means that the method will receive a borrowed pointer to `self`; i.e. the type of `self` is `&VecCircle<T>`. Therefore, the method doesn't have ownership of the `VecCircle<T>`.

`find_and_remove` tries to call [`into_iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.into_iter) on a [`VecDeque`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html), and `into_iter` receives its argument by value (`self` rather than `&self` or `&mut self`). Because of this, Rust interprets `self.0` as trying to move the `VecDeque` out of the `VecCircle`. However, that's not allowed as you can't move anything out of borrowed content, as moving from some location makes that location invalid. But we can't just tell the caller *"Hey, I just invalidated `self`, stop using it!"*; if we wanted to do that, we'd have to specify `self` in the parameter list, rather than `&self`.

But that's not what you're trying to do here. `into_iter` would take ownership of the `VecDeque` and therefore **destroy it**. There are other ways to obtain an iterator for the `VecDeque` without destroying it. Here, we should use [`iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.iter), which takes `&self`.

Then, `find_and_remove` tries to call [`remove`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.remove). `remove` takes `&mut self`, i.e. a mutable reference to a `VecDeque`. However, we can't borrow `self.0` as mutable, because `self` is not itself a mutable borrow. We can't just upgrade an immutable borrow to a mutable borrow: it is invalid to have both an immutable borrow and a mutable borrow usable at the same time. The solution here is to change `&self` to `&mut self` in the parameter list.

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

trait VecCircleTraits<T: Eq> {
    fn new() -> VecCircle<T>;
    fn find_and_remove(&mut self, _: &T) -> Option<T>;
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct VecCircle<T: Eq>(VecDeque<T>);

impl<T: Eq> VecCircleTraits<T> for VecCircle<T> {
    fn new() -> VecCircle<T> {
        return VecCircle(VecDeque::<T>::new());
    }

    fn find_and_remove(&mut self, key: &T) -> Option<T> {
        let search_index: Option<usize> =  self.0.iter().position(|x| x == key);
        if let Some(index) =  search_index {
            self.0.remove(index)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I also changed the `key` parameter to `&T` to solve another error, this time in the closure passed to `position`. Since `iter` iterates over references to the items in the `VecDeque`, `position` passes references to the closure. Since `find_and_remove` doesn't actually need to take ownership of the key, it should just receive an immutable borrow to it, so that both `x` and `key` are of type `&T` and thus we can apply `==` to them.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, you don't have ownership of the `VecCircle` inside the `find_and_remove` method. All you need to know is in the function definition:

```
impl<T: Eq> VecCircleTraits<T> for VecCircle<T> {
    fn find_and_remove(&self, key: T) -> Option<T>
}
```

This means that you are **borrowing a reference** to `VecCircle`. The longer way to write this would be

```
fn find_and_remove(self: &VecCircle, key: T) -> Option<T>
```

Perhaps that is more evident?

Since you don't have ownership of `self`, you cannot have ownership of `self.0`.